# Are read/writes to a socketpair completely synchronous or is there buffering?

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, posix

Does the OS provide any kind of a buffer when using a `socketpair` for communication? Ie, if I do

```
int sv[2];
socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv);
```

will a `write(sv[0], ...)` block until a `read(sv[1], ...)` is also taking place? Or will some amount of data be stored somewhere in the OS even if a `read` was not taking place when the `write` occured?

Comment: There is a buffer.  Pipes, fifos, socketpair, etc., would be damn near useless without a buffer.  `My guess is the buffer size is PIPE_BUF bytes but I have never seen that definitively documented anywhere.  In any case, you *will* block if you fill the buffer (or error with EAGAIN if non-blocking).

Comment: For sockets you can set buffer size via `setsockopt`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no buffering in C for `socketpair` sockets like there is `STDIO` buffering with `fopen`. However, there is a buffer in your operating system. The buffer sizes can be set with `setsockopt` using `SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` for send and receive just like any normal socket. The default values are operating system dependent. `man -s7 socket` will help here.

The buffering may be slightly dependent on socket type. For instance, I think with datagram sockets you are guaranteed atomicity. In most (all?) POSIX operating systems the only available address family is `AF_UNIX`. I believe you can use `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM`, and the buffering technique will depend on which of these you choose. From memory the `SOCK_DGRAM` will simply fail if you use more than the available buffer size (as the datagrams are transmitted atomically), whereas `SOCK_STREAM` will block; I'd check that before relying on it.